# Determine a differentiable function $y = f(x)$ which has the properties: $f '(x)=f(x)^2$ and $f(0)= -{1\over 2}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine a differentiable function $y = f(x)$ which has the properties: $f '(x)=f(x)^2$ and $f(0)= -{1\over 2}$.

Can someone solve this problem I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

It will be a great help.

Comment: You should put the question in the body of the question, not the title.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $\phi(x) = -{1 \over f(x)}$, then $\phi'(x) = {f'(x) \over f(x)^2}$.

Hence you want to solve $\phi'(x) = 1$ subject to $\phi(0) = 2$. This gives
$\phi(x) = 2+x$ and so $f(x) = -{1 \over 2+x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\displaystyle \left( \frac{1}{x+c} \right)' = - \frac{1}{(x+c)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

we should solve the D.E
$$y'-y^2=0$$
the general solution is
$$y=\frac{1}{c-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{df}{dx} = f^2$$
$$\int \left(f^{-2} \frac{df}{dx} - 1\right) dx = 0$$
$$-f^{-1} - x - C = 0$$
$$f = -\frac{1}{x+C}$$
$$f(0) = -\frac{1}{C} = -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$C=2$$
$$f=-\frac{1}{x+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{dy}{dx} &= y^2 \\
               dx &= \dfrac{dy}{y^2} \\
            x + c &= -\dfrac 1y \\
                y &= -\dfrac{1}{x+c} \\
\hline
         y(0) &= -\dfrac 12 \\
   -\dfrac 1c &= - \dfrac 12 \\
         c &= 2 \\
\hline
   y &= -\dfrac{1}{2+x}
\end{align}